# Given two convergent sequences find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n^n+b_n^n+2018}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I tried to solve this question, but can't get to a correct answer...

> Let $a_n,b_n$ be two sequences s.t. 
>   $$
> a_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}a>1,\quad b_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}b>1.
> $$ 
>   Find 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n^n+b_n^n+2018}$$

I tried to use sandwich, but it seems that the bounds I choose not working.

I checked in W|A for some examples and I think that the answer should be $\max\{a,b\}$.

Could someone hint me?

Comment: You recieved 4 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Comment: @5xum, will do, thanks for notifying :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$a_n^n + b_n^n + 2018 = a_n^n\left(1 + \left(\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)^n + \frac{2018}{a_n^n}\right)$$

Now, use the fact that $\sqrt[n]{A\cdot B} =\sqrt[n]A \cdot \sqrt[n]B$ and you should be almost there. If $a>b$, then the inside of the parentheses goes to $1$, otherwise, it goes to $2$, but in either case, the $n$-th root of it converges to $1$.

Comment: $a > 1$ is given. Perhaps you want to assume that $a \ge b$?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Yeah, that was my assumption.

Comment: You can't assume $a>b$; they might be equal.

Comment: If we only assume $a,b\ge0$, we get the limit to be $\max(a,b,1)$

Comment: @robjohn True. But with the added assumption of $a,b>1$ (which is written in the original question), we also have $\max\{a,b,1\} = \max\{a,b\}$, so your statement, while true, isn't particularly relevant.

Comment: @5xum: other than generalizing the result (and perhaps offering a better understanding), but as the question is stated, my comment is not relevant.

Comment: I am trying to justify that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1+\left(\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)^n+\frac{2018}{a_n^n}}=1$$ to me it seems that I need to use that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\sqrt[n]{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n}$$ is it true? and if so, how does one prove that?

Comment: @y12 Clearly, what you wrote is not true since on the RHS, the value of $n$ is not even defined. However, what you *can* use in finding the limit is that, so long as $x\in (1,\infty)$, you have $1<\sqrt[n]{x} <x$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @y12 Also, you can use the fact that for any $x>0$, the sequence $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence with a limit of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

A small issue:

Let $a \ge b$, and $n \ge n_0$ , s.t.

$a_n, b_n \gt 1.$

$f(n):=$

$ a_n(1+(b_n/a_n)^n +2018/a_n^n)^{1/n}.$

Note : For $n \ge n_0$

$(1+(b_n/a_n)^n +2018/a_n^n)$ is bounded.

Let $M_{n_0} >0$, real, be an upper bound.

$a_n < f(n) < a_n (M_{n_0})^{1/n}$.

Take the limit.

Comment: Such an $n_0$ does not necessarily exist if $a=b$. We might have $b_n>a_n$ for arbitrarily large $n$ (or for all $n$). Annoying, I know.

Comment: TonyK.Quite annoying:)I'll try to fix it.Thanks

Comment: TonyK.Hopefully better now:)Thanks.

Comment: An alternative fix would be to note that $a_n^n+b_n^n+2018=A_n^n+B_n^n+2018$ where $A_n=\max(a_n,b_n)\to A=\max(a,b)$ and $B_n=\min(a_n,b_n)\to B=\min(a,b)$.

Comment: Barry Cipra.Very nice(!), thank you.Greetings.

Comment: Barry Cipra.Why not write a hint or a short answer?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\large{\sqrt[n]{a_n^n+b_n^n+2018}=e^{\frac{\log\left(a_n^n+b_n^n+2018\right)}{n}}}$$

and for $a\ge b>1$ wlog we obtain

$$\frac{\log\left(a_n^n+b_n^n+2018\right)}{n}=\log a_n+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{b_n^n}{a_n^n}+\frac{2018}{a_n^n}\right)}{n} \to \log a$$

therefore the given limit is equal to $\max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: You can't assume $a>b$; they might be equal. Every answer so far has made this mistake!

Comment: @TonyK Yes you are right, we need also to consider the case a=b, I fix that.

Comment: @TonyK Now it should be fixed including also the case with equality. The result doesn't change. Thanks to have pointed that out! Bye